# puts vs printf en lenjuage C

Tags: c

Estoy empezando a programar en C.

¿Cuáles son as diferencias entre `puts` y `printf`?¿En que casos conviene usar una u otra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A primera vista, la diferencia principal es que `puts` es más simple y automáticamente añade una nueva línea a la salida (CRLF en Windows), mientras que `printf` no lo hace.

Hay una diferencia más sutil, y es que mientras el resultado de `puts(mistr);` y `printf(mistr);` parece equivalente (a excepción del CRLF ya mencionado), en el último el argumento es interpretado como una *cadena de formato*. El resultado generamlmente va a ser el mismo, excepto que ´mistr´ tenga caracteres de control (`"%"`).

En el caso que `mistr` no sea una literal, bajo el control del programador, sino una variable, en realidad nunca habría que llamar a `printf(mistr);`, sino utilizar su equivalente `printf("%s", mistr);`

No hacerlo se considera peligroso, pues puede llegar a ser explotado si un atacante logra controlar el contenido de la variable `mistr`.

```
char * miMensage;
// ... miMensage es asignado en tiempo de corrida, contenido impredecible.
printf(miMensage);  // <--- ALERTA! (¿qué pasa si miMensage contiene caracter(es) '%'?) 
puts(miMensage);    // correcto
printf("%s\n",miMensage); // correcto, resultado equivalente al anterior, quizás menos eficiente
```

Lo mismo aplica a `fputs` vs. `fprintf`, pero `fputs` no agrega el CRLF.

Con información de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16813480/255257) (en inglés).

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Cuáles son as diferencias entre `puts` y `printf`?

La escritura con formato. Mientras que `puts` escribe directamente lo que se le facilita como parámetro, `printf` lo formatea anes de escribir.

> ¿En qué casos conviene usar una u otra?

Usa `printf` cuando debas dar formato a la salida, puedes usar `puts` en caso contrario; aunque en mi opinión, usaría `printf` en ambos casos por dar homogeneidad al código.